# How to add third party libraries in Angular 4 using Webpack?

Tags: javascript, angular, import, webpack, angular-cli

I've recently tried adding js libraries (such as chartist or datatables) to my Angular 4 project using Webpack but I'm stuck. I successfully added to my project js libraries from the npm library, they were listed in the node_modules folder and in the package.json file.

The problem seems to be that typescript libraries are allowed but not js libraries. I tried importing a js library first in app.module.ts then in NgModules, then in the right component, it didn't work. I then tried importing it in the script table in the angular-cli.json file, it didn't work either.

Could you please tell me how you would proceed injecting a third party library in an Angular 4 component for example?

Comment: Welcome to SO. This is really too broad of a question. You need to read up on beginner tutorials, it is a very basic concept you are asking about.

Answer (score 0):

As previously stated this question is too broad. Generally if it is a non angular specific js library then you will be importing it via angular.json file. **How** that library is triggered off is completely down to how that library operates.